# Is there a general term for a vertex in a skeletal formula?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

When a carbon atom is single bonded to a residue, it is referred to simply as "methyl." When it is single bonded to two attachments, it is methanediyl, or methylene bridge. When it is single bonded to one atom and double bonded to another, it is called methine. Is there a generic term for the class of single-carbon-atom groups of the form  $\ce{CH$_n$}$, or to an unmarked vertex in a skeletal formula with sufficiently many hydrogen atoms to satisfy valence?

Comment: The generic term is "carbon atom".

Comment: Even when the vertex also denotes accompanying single-bonded hydrogen atoms to the carbon atom? It is only referred to as a "carbon atom"? Couldn't that be potentially ambiguous (confused with a carbon atom without any such hydrogen atoms) and misleading in certain contexts (such as calculation of molecular weights, treatment of point groups, etc.)?

Comment: You might say methaneXyl, where for n>1: X is numerical prefix from n, for n=1: X is  "-1-" (to prevent "disharmony"); i.e. methane-1-yl, methanediyl, methanetriyl, but these certainly are not preferred, and probably not generic in a way you ask for. Do you have a real case context where you did want to use it?